# Link node to an other node SpriteKit - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, image-rotation

I'm creating a game, I have a grid and a ball, and I want that the ball follow the position of the grid, please see the image.

How can I do it ?

[image: Image of my game]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the ball as a child node of the grid. For example:

```
grid.addChild(ball)
```

For more information see *Creating the Node Tree* in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html